# Updating table based on IDs from seperate database

Tags: mysql, database, join

I need to switch ID_1 from DATABASE_1 to ID_2 from ID_2 from DATABASE_2 where DATABASE_1.ID_1 = DATABASE_2.ID_3

```
UPDATE `table_1` 
SET `DATABASE_1`.`table_1`.`ID_1`= `DATABASE_2`.`table_2`.`ID_2`
WHERE `DATABASE_1`.`table_1`.`ID_1` = `DATABASE_2`.`table_2`.`DealerID`
```

Above is the type of statement I was thinking of. Here is the structure

```
DATABASE_1
table_1
    ID_1
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5

DATABASE_2
table_2
    ID_2            ID_3
    10              1               
    20              2
    30              3
    40              4
    50              5
```

I think I need to JOIN these somehow... or add columns onto table_1 and alter them. I am bad at joining, and so far I have

```
SELECT ID_2 , ID_3 FROM DATABASE_2.table_2 t2 JOIN DATABASE_1.ID_1 t2 ON t1.ID_1 = t2.ID_3
```

but that doesn't update it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `JOIN`

```
UPDATE DATABASE_1.table_1 AS t1
JOIN DATABASE_2.table_2 AS t2 ON t1.ID_1 = t2.DealerID
SET t1.ID_1 = t2.ID_2
```

Comment: Fantastic, that AS t1 and AS t2 was what I needed

Comment: You can do it without the `AS` clauses, that just means you have to write out the full name of the table each time you refer to it. It doesn't affect the overall structure of the query.